# Localization in B2C Custom Policy - Missing required elements

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I have to localize a sign-up, and a password reset custom policy in German, and I have a few questions regarding that:

1. There seem to be no default translation for the "Missing required element: {0}" error, which shows when I for example enter a whitespace in my Verification Code textbox, and click "Verify":

[image]

I have then added this line to my localization file in order to add my own text:

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="ErrorMessage" StringId="UserMessageIfMissingRequiredElement">Fehlendes erforderliches Element: {0}</LocalizedString>
```

This works somewhat, however, it ends up showing me the this error message, where you can see the placeholder ({0}) is not filled:

[image]

According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/localization-string-ids#sign-up-and-self-asserted-pages-error-messages), the {0} placeholder should be the right one to use here.

2. Similarly, I am trying to add custom texts to the errors around the input fields, e.g.

[image]

and for Verification Code:

[image]

There's a business requirement that e.g. "Email" should be called "E-Mail-Adresse" in the flow, but when using the LocalizedString:

```
<LocalizedString ElementType="UxElement" StringId="required_field_descriptive">{0} ist erforderlich.</LocalizedString>
```

the placeholder seems to be taking the type of the input field rather than the DisplayName of the ClaimType, as otherwise stated in the documentation.
Can I customize the texts being inserted into the placeholders, so that I can for example show "E-Mail-Adresse ist erforderlich." and "Verification code ist erforderlich.", respectively?

I am using selfasserted:2.1.19 pages for both flows.

Comment: Are you looking to customize the error codes of input fields or input field names?

Comment: Thanks for responding, @ShwetaM. The input field names are fine. For issue 1, I'm having issues with the custom policy not picking up the input field name that I have given the field, when using the {0} placeholder in a translation. It is picking up the input field name just fine when not adding my own translation, here the whole text just isn't localized. For issue 2, it seems that the {0} placeholder is taking the input field type as input, rather than the input field name, which I would have expected. This is denying me from being able to translate the part picked up by the {0} placeholder.